# Does Unity compress downloaded audio files?

Tags: unity-game-engine

As I know Unity will automatically compress the audio that I have in the project base on my build target.

[Unity doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioClip.html)

Since my target is mobile, if I put .mp3 file Unity will encode to their .mp3 again (double compression) which leads to quality degrade.

My question is my audio file is in the server and user need to download the audio file first, does Unity compress the downloaded audio files?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to download the mp3 file at runtime then I guess you are using WWW to load the audioclip into unity. You can use GetAudioClip() for an uncompressed file or GetAudioClipCompressed, these functions change in 5.6 to WWWAudioExtensions.GetAudioClipCompressed and WWWAudioExtensions.GetAudioClip.